# Where are windows command prompt customized colors stored?

Tags: windows, command-line, colors

I like to customize each of the 16 colors in my windows command prompt, but setting them up manually is a slow and painful process (due to some bugs in the colors tab of Console Windows Properties). I'd like a way to import these settings quickly when I am setting up a new machine.

[image]

My question is - where are these settings actually stored? In the registry somewhere? In a config file?

Comment: good find, that looks like it has the settings I'm looking for.